# React Native Image ALT text?

Tags: javascript, react-native, image

My app uses an API to render images(red squares) to the screen based on a user selection.
However, some images won't load at times and I'm not sure how to handle this error (looking for best practices).
I have already implemented a ActivityIndicator for the container (blue box) where the images are being displayed.
Is there a way to add a ALT text to react native or something better?

Here my code:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

const callAPI = async () => {
    const api = await fetch(
      `my API`
    );
    const data = await api.json();
    setData(data);
then rendering this:

  <FlatList
    data={data}
    keyExtractor={(item, index)=>{return item.date}}
    numColumns={numberOfCols}
    renderItem={({item, index})=>(
      <View style={styles.viewpic}>
        <Image 
source={{uri:item.url}}/>
       </View>
```

[image: App picture]

Thank you!

Comment: Have a look in [the documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/image). You could use a `defaultSource` and / or handle the `onError` event

Comment: @Phil I'm gonna take a look at the docs again! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try progressive image loading, so it will be more light to show the thumbnail image first before the real image

Refference : https://medium.com/react-native-training/progressive-image-loading-in-react-native-e7a01827feb7